# Using JavaService to add Windows Service

Tags: java, service, windows-services

I have created a Java application (runs infinite loop) (with many Java class files) that also uses `log4j.jar` and `snmp4j.jar? . In order to run the application, I need to provide some input arguments as follows:

```
C:\APP>java myApp.class arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6
```

where `myApp.class` contains the main handler.

This application works fine under command line execution. However, I want to create a Windows service for this application so that it will run whenever the PC is started. Also, if the service is down for whatever reason, it will get re-started under Windows Services tool.

I tried to use **JavaService** for my purpose, by executing the following command:

```
C:\APP>JavaService.exe -install MyService "C:\java\jdk1.6.0.29\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" -start myApp.class -params arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6
The MyService automatic service was successfully installed
```

I can see my `MyService` appeared under Administrative Tools->Services

However, when I did a start of `MyService`, it started and then stopped :(

```
Service dialog:
The MyService on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the Performance Logs and Alerts service.
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: When creating the service try "-err D:\Logs\javaservice.log" and it will tell you which library is missed and you need to add using -Djava.class.path=something.jar

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to specify the classpath?

You do this with a setting like this:

```
-Djava.class.path={JDK_HOME}\lib\tools.jar;<your jar 1>;<your jar 2>
```

As an example, we use a script to install JBoss, similar to the one discussed/shown here:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JavaService

HTH

Comment: PS You can see error messages from your service in Event Viewer in windows. Look in "Windows Logs" then "Application".

Comment: I tried doing -Djava.class.path as suggested, but still not able to start the windows service :(

Comment: That's a shame. Did you look in those Windows Event logs for errors from your service?

Comment: The Windows Event logs just reported "The MyService service failed to start"

Comment: Is that the only event message? You have not told the service where to pick up your jars from

Comment: Oh! You are right! I missed out the earlier event messages. The messages started with "Could not call the service method" -> "Failed to invoke the service start function" -> "The MyService service failed to start"

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use 64-bit JVM you must use 64-bit JavaService. Otherwise you will get following error in Windows Event logs:

> The LoadLibrary function failed for the following reason: LoadLibrary is not a valid Win32 application.

Second, use `-out` and `-err` parameters of JavaService to log stdout and stderr from your java code.